# mysql concat string with result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this

```
Name  Country State
John  US      California
```

I want to do a select statement with a concat so I get something like this

```
http:// getmehelp / US / John.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT ( 'http://getmehelp/', country , '/', name , '.txt') AS link;
```

Answer (score 2):

The query you are looking for should be this one:

```
SELECT concat('http://getmehelp/',Country,'/',Name,'.txt')
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat('http://getmehelp/', country, '/', name, '.txt')
from your_table
```