# CONCAT without '\'

Tags: mysql

I used the example at the link below to use CONCAT to append a file path to the beginning of the result from a column. However, when I use it, it adds a '\' before all the '/'.

Link: [mysql concat string with result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066534/mysql-concat-string-with-result)

My query:

```
"CONCAT('$this->unit_images_path', '/' , photo.photo_name) AS photo_name"
```

This returns something like 'images_path\/photo.jpg'.

How can I use the CONCAT here so the '\' is not added?

Comment: Did you forget the backslash in your example? Because I see no "\" in it.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about the system stripping a single '\\', so I added a second one. I think you can see it fine now.

Comment: HA. In the original post, I had to use 2 '\', but in these comments, I can use a single one it appears.

Answer (score 2):

The `\` is coming from your code `$this->unit_images_path`

Just trim the `\` from the string in PHP and then use the trimmed string instead. You can use the php `rtrim` function to do this.

Example:

```
$new_path = rtrim($this->unit_images_path, '\\'); // don't forget to escape the \ in PHP.
....("CONCAT('$new_path', '/' , photo.photo_name) AS photo_name")
```

Comment: Thanks. That's not it. $this->unit_images_path = 'unit_images'.

Comment: OK, what if you add the '/' in PHP instead of in the MySql query?

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it does the same thing. Really baffeling. I just went ahead and changed the solution so the path is not added here.